# Data getting inserted into database when no request is being sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

So I have a React JS app that's sending data to my database as well as images to server. When I make a request on the front-end it's sending the data and the image.
For some reason even when I don't send data from the front-end INSERTS are being made with that same information but different id's because of the uuid.

**NodeJS**

```
const addData = (request, response) => {
const uuid = uuidv4(); 
let album_id;

 db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *' , [request.body.title, request.body.date, request.body.description, uuid])
    .then(res => {
      album_id = res.rows[0].id;
      console.log('INSERT ' + res.rowCount);
      console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    }).then(() => {
       const dbQueryPromises = [];
       for (let i = 0; i < request.body.files.length; i++) {
        dbQueryPromises.push(db.pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (id, name, link, index, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (album_id, index) DO NOTHING RETURNING *', [uuid, request.body.files[i].name, request.body.files[i].link, request.body.files[i].index, album_id]))
      }
        return Promise.all(dbQueryPromises);
        }).then(res => {
         console.log('Array of INSERT result for second insert: ');
    }).then(() => {
        db.pool.query(
        'INSERT INTO file (name, type, size, path, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (album_id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *',
        [request.file.filename, request.file.mimetype, request.file.size, request.file.path, album_id]);
      }).then((res) => {
         console.log("INSERT INTO file(images) " + request.body.data);
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));

  }
```

**NodeJS(What db is in the code above)**

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'me',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'api',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
})
```

**NodeJS(index.js)**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public')
    }, 
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/albums', upload.single('file'), apiCall.addData);
```

**And the ReactJS code:**
https://gist.github.com/DDavis1025/db77b2f7a44c2ea26a8b18ba7aa70952

Also I don't believe the re-insert is being made if I leave the page on the front-end and re-render..

Comment: Try sending a HTTP status 200 OK after apiCall.addData is successful, or HTTP 5xx if unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you show me what that looks like? What's HTTP 5xx?

Comment: @LoveenDyall Can you share some code?

Comment: @LoveenDyall I added a status 201 in my code and it started working. I don't think I have it in the appropriate place though. Can you add some code so I know where to put it?